# Does a list clear delete the objects previously contained

Tags: c#, .net, list

Imagining i have :

```
List<MyObject> MyList = new List<MyObject>();
MyObject obj1 = new MyObject();
MyObject obj2 = new MyObject();
MyList.Add(obj1);
MyList.Add(obj2);
```

Does a

```
MyList.Clear();
```

Delete the instantiated : 'obj1','obj2' ? Or are they kept in the memory but the list is just now empty ?

Comment: The objects are still alive, but the list is empty. Objects are removed by the Garbage Collector (GC) as soon as there is no reference to it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as you have a reference to an object and you can access it in your code it is there in memory and garbage collector is not collecting it. so the answer is **NO, they are kept in the memory**

you can read more about garbage collection [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx).

if the code was like this

```
List<MyObject> MyList = new List<MyObject>();
MyList.Add(new MyObject());
MyList.Add(new MyObject());
```

then when you call `MyList.Clear()` you have no reference to your created `MyObject`s so garbage collector will collect them and delete them from memory in it's next run.
if you want to remove `obj1` and `obj2` from memory after clearing list you should use

```
obj1 = null;
obj2 = null;
GC.Collect()
```

but be aware of consequences of forcing garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

the `clear` function just clear the list.
`obj1`  and `obj2` will not be `null`.
you can easily check it by printing the objects:

```
Console.WriteLine(obj1);
```

Comment: I believe this is `C#` not java

Answer (score 0):

> Delete the instantiated : 'obj1','obj2' ? Or are they kept in the memory but the list is just now empty ?

They are kept in the memory until there are no reference to your objects and GC deletes them. In this case only your list will be empty.You can easily test this by trying to access members of your object after calling `Clear` method.